# How to fix this Tkinter button bug

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter

Whenever I run the program, the buttons show up however the images do not show and instead appear as a grey space. Also, all the buttons apart from the 'finish' button are unpressable (see the image attached).[image: Button bug]

```
def NoFood():
    TotalCalories = NoBreakfast.calories
    NoFoodOption = 1

def BoiledEggsFunct():
    TotalCalories = BoiledEggs.calories + TotalCalories

def FriedEggsFunct():
    TotalCalories = FriedEggs.calories + TotalCalories

def ScrambledEggsFunct():
    TotalCalories = ScrambledEggs.calories + TotalCalories

def PoachedEggsFunct():
    TotalCalories = PoachedEggs.calories + TotalCalories

def ToastFunct():
    TotalCalories = Toast.calories + TotalCalories

def BaconFunct():
    TotalCalories = Bacon.calories + TotalCalories

def CerealFunct():
    TotalCalories = Cereal.calories + TotalCalories

def PorridgeFunct():
    TotalCalories = Porridge.calories + TotalCalories

def FinishScreen():
    FinishWindow = Toplevel()

    if TotalCalories > 0 and TotalCalories < 1000:
        HealthyLabel = Label(FinishWindow, text = "Congratulations, you are healthy!", font=("Comic Sans MS", 25), fg = "light green",
              bg = "black")
        HealthyLabel.grid(columnspan=10)

    elif TotalCalories > 1000:
        UnhealthyLabel = Label(FinishWindow, text = "Try to eat healthier tomorrow. See personalised advice", font=("Comic Sans MS", 25), fg = "yellow",
              bg = "black")
        UnhealthyLabel.grid(columnspan=10)

    elif NoFoodOption == 1:
        NoFoodLabel = Label(FinishWindow, text = "Not eating can be harmful to your health. See personalised advice", font=("Comic Sans MS", 25), fg = "red",
              bg = "black")
        NoFoodLabel.grid(columnspan=10)

    else:
        Error = Label(FinishWindow, text = "error", font=("Comic Sans MS", 25), fg = "red",
              bg = "black")
        NoFoodLabel.grid(columnspan=10)

BoiledEggsPhoto = PhotoImage(file="BoiledEgg.gif")
BoiledEggsButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Boiled Eggs", command=BoiledEggsFunct, image=BoiledEggsPhoto, compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)
BoiledEggsButton.grid(column=1,row=3)

ScrambledEggsPhoto = PhotoImage(file="ScrambledEgg.gif")
ScrambledEggsButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Scrambled Eggs", command=ScrambledEggsFunct, image=ScrambledEggsPhoto, compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)
ScrambledEggsButton.grid(column=2,row=3)

FriedEggsPhoto = PhotoImage(file="FriedEgg.gif")
FriedEggsButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Fried Eggs", command = FriedEggsFunct, image=FriedEggsPhoto, compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)
FriedEggsButton.grid(column=3, row=3)

PoachedEggsPhoto = PhotoImage(file="PoachedEgg.gif")
PoachedEggsButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Poached Eggs", command = PoachedEggsFunct, image=PoachedEggsPhoto,  compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)
PoachedEggsButton.grid(column=1, row=4)

ToastPhoto = PhotoImage(file="Toast.gif")
ToastButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Toast", command = ToastFunct, image=ToastPhoto, compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)
ToastButton.grid(column=2,row=4)

BaconPhoto = PhotoImage(file="Bacon.gif")
BaconButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Bacon", command = BaconFunct, image=BaconPhoto, compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)
BaconButton.grid(column=3, row=4)

CerealPhoto = PhotoImage(file="Cereal.gif")
CerealButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Cereal", command = CerealFunct, image=CerealPhoto, compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)
CerealButton.grid(column=1, row=5)

PorridgePhoto = PhotoImage(file="Porridge.gif")
PorridgeButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Porridge", command = PorridgeFunct, image=PorridgePhoto, compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)
PorridgeButton.grid(column=2, row=5)

NoBreakfastPhoto = PhotoImage(file="NoBreakfast.gif")
NoBreakfastButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text= "None", command = NoFood, image=NoBreakfastPhoto, compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)
NoBreakfastButton.grid(column=3, row =5)

EndScreen = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Finish", command = FinishScreen, width=12)
EndScreen.grid(column=2,row=6)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Is your code that creates the buttons actually outside of any function, as shown in the excerpt you posted?  The usual reason for this problem is that you used only local variables (within a function) to refer to the images, which results in them being garbage collected as soon as the function exits.  The usual fix for that problem is to store the image as an attribute of the widget that uses it: `BaconButton.photo = BaconPhoto` for example.

Comment: It's all within a function.

So would I need to do:

`BaconPhoto = PhotoImage(file="bacon.gif")

BaconButton.photo = BaconPhoto

BaconButton = Button(FoodSelectionWindow, text="Bacon", command = BaconFunct, image=BaconButton.Photo, compound=LEFT, height=100, width = 200)`

Comment: Exactly - you just need to ensure that the image object lives for at least as long as the widget that uses it.